# Magento 2 Get Email to Friend URL using Product ID

Tags: magento2, product

I have to get Email to Friend URL using Product ID Using Object Manager.

Can anyone any idea of it?

Answer (score 0):

Using Below Code you get to Email to Friend URL using Product ID.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productObj = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
$emailHelper = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product');
$emailUrl = $emailHelper->getEmailToFriendUrl($productObj);
```

Hope it will helps to you